# How to extrapolate RELEASE or LATEST version from maven repository?

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

With this command I copy a single file out of artifactory:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:copy 
-Dartifact=com.example:blah:RELEASE:war 
-DoutputDirectory=/tmp -Dmdep.useBaseVersion=true
```

I should get blah-1.2.3.war in my tmp dir.

But to process the resulting file in a shell script, I cannot use RELEASE of course. I end up with blah-RELEASE.war not found. I'm searching for an elegant way to extrapolate this version string from artifactory or nexus so I can manipulate the resulting file using its absolute file name, no wildcards, and without interrogating /tmp with ls or find.

At this moment, I fetch the pom for the war, and grep/sed the version. In jenkins do something like this

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:copy \
-DoutputDirectory=${WORKSPACE} \
-Dartifact=com.example:blah:RELEASE:pom \
-Dmdep.stripVersion=true

VERSION=$( grep -A 1 "<artifactId>blah</artifactId>" \
${WORKSPACE}/blah.pom | sed -nr 's|.*<version>(.*)</version>.*|\1|p' )
```

Comment: did you check the `outputAbsoluteArtifactFilename` parameter, per [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html) it would print out the absolute file name you need. adding `-DoutputAbsoluteArtifactFilename=true` to your first command

Comment: Yes, it makes no difference to the output as far as I can tell. I tried it again, but no joy.